# How to split lines from a set of text input files which has movie titles(no spaces and no commas), followed by white space, followed by rating

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

The text in the files are in no particular order and we need to assume there are multiple lines for same movie. This is what the input might look:

```
batman_returns 4.0
The_Dark_Knight 4.0
batman_returns 5.0
Captain_America 5.0
Captain_America 4.0
```

Need to compute the average rating for each movie and have the output in sorted order. For example, the output should look like this:

[(4.5, batman_returns), (4.5, Captain_America), (4.0, The_Dark_Knight)]

Need to complete the problem using Python Spark code.

Comment: Please try and post your code, even if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python spark but if it's similar to python then:

```
import pandas as pd

# Import text file
df = pd.read_csv('movies.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = ["movie", "rating"]

# Find mean
avg = df.groupby(['movie']).mean('rating').reset_index()

# Create upper case dummy column to handle lower/upper case sorting
avg['upper_movies'] = avg['movie'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())

# Sort values by dummy column, drop dummy column.
avg = avg.sort_values(['upper_movies']).drop(['upper_movies'], axis=1)

# Create list of tuple by iterating through rows
output = [(row['rating'], row['movie']) for idx, row in avg.iterrows()]
print(output)
```